# VSTS Copy files to remote machine via SSH

Tags: linux, azure, ssh, azure-pipelines

I am deploying my project on Linux based VM via Copy Files Over SSH step in VSTS build definition. Below is the folder structure.

```
root
 -- .git
 -- .gitignore
 -- folder1
 -- folder2
 .
 .
 .
```

I want to ignore .git folder when copying file to Linux based staging server (VM on Azure). I tried below minimatch patterns but none of them working.

```
**/!(.git)
**/!.git
```

[image]

Let me know what i am missing and how can i ignore the .git folder. I tried looking on internet but nothing found.

Comment: What's the result of !**/.git/**?

Comment: @starain-MSFT this does the work. Please post it as answer and explain it a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is (ignore all files in .git folder):

```
!**/.git/**
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on information from https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh following should work:

```
!**/.git
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern box is multi line and should have an entry per line:

**

!**\folderodontwant*

This way you can have multiple exclusion and inclusions with less complexity.

Comment: Still copying .git folder, dot (.) can cause the problem in the minimatch ? Is there any escape character to make dot part of the pattern. I tried 
**
!**\.git*